# Visual Studio 2019 - Identify Specific Color Element Within a Color Theme

Tags: visual-studio, themes, resharper, color-scheme, visual-studio-2019

I'm using the Visual Studio 2019 dark theme and also have ReSharper installed.  There are a number of styles where the background and foreground combination clashes a bit and makes it difficult to read some of the text:

[image: vs 2019 dark color theme]

I'd like to darken the foreground for a few of these text highlights but can't locate the specific color element within the theme editor.

[image: color theme editor]

Does anyone know of a way to pinpoint the active color element within the theme editor via a shortcut or menu action?  Something like a "Find style for current element"?

Thank you

Comment: (As with older versions of VS) I sometimes find myself scrolling down the list looking for a similar colour and then seeing if the name makes sense. In your first screenshot the background is slightly pink and seems to be just a single symbol; therefore isn't highlight current line.

Comment: Good call on scrolling for the color.  This one turned out to be "ReSharper Completion Replacement Range".  Thanks.